# java generics: getting class of a class with generic parameters

Tags: java, generics

I am curious how to make this work

```
 Class<Map<String,String>> food = Map.class;
```

That obviously doesn't work. I would want something like this

```
 Class<Map<String,String>> food = Map<String,String>.class;
```

but this seems like not a valid java sytax.

How can make this work?

**EDIT**: 
The reason I want this is because I have a method like this

```
   protected <ConfigType> ConfigValue<ConfigType> getSectionConfig(String name, Class<ConfigType> configType) {
        return config.getConfig(name);
    }
```

I would like to call this as so

```
ConfigValue<Map<String,Object>> config = getSectionConfig("blah", Map<String,Object>.class>);
Map<String,Value> val = config.value();
```

Comment: Why would you want this?

Comment: `Map<String,String>.class` can't exist. A `Type` that describes that signature can though, and you can use a [super type token](http://gafter.blogspot.sk/2006/12/super-type-tokens.html) to get that type, but `Type`s don't have the reflection capabilities of a `Class`.

Comment: How make it work or how make it joke?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza updated my question with use case.

Comment: @nikpon what joke? I dont get what your comment means,

Comment: Have you added the class parameter to `getSectionConfig` merely because you want to indicate the return type to the compiler?

Do you realize that there will be casting somewhere, probably in the implementation of `getSectionConfig` or its dependencies, because you can't implement a dynamically-typed map in static fashion?

Comment: @JudgeMental  Yes but I want to limit casting to just one place. Not all over my code.

Answer (score 19):

Do a brute cast

```
    Class<Map<String,String>> clazz = 
             (Class<Map<String,String>>)(Class)Map.class;
```

this is not theoretically correct, but it is not our fault. We need such hacks some times.

Answer (score 4):

According to the [JLS, Section 15.8.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.8.2), you can't do that, because:

> The type of C.class, where C is the name of a class, interface, or array type (§4.3), is Class<C>.

The closest you can come is

```
Class<Map> food = Map.class;
```

Comment: That is what I have currently but its not entirely typesafe and I have to do casting. :-\

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but may be ParameterizedTypeReference class can help you?

```
private static final ParameterizedTypeReference<Map<String, Object>> YOUR_TYPE_NAME = new ParameterizedTypeReference<Map<String, Object>>() {};
```